# Convert a third-party render prop component into a hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using an old-style third-party component that accepts a render prop, in this case [visx Zoom](https://airbnb.io/visx/docs/zoom):

```
return (
  <Zoom scaleXMin={0.5} scaleXMax={4}>
    {zoom => (
      <svg>
        <g transform={zoom.toString()}>
          ...
        </g>
      </svg>
    )}
  </Zoom>
)
```

Can I refactor that component into a hook, without touching its source code?

Something like:

```
const [Zoom, zoom] = useZoom({ scaleXMin: 0.5, scaleXMax: 4 })

return (
  <Zoom>
    <svg>
      <g transform={zoom.toString()}>
        ...
      </g>
    </svg>        
  </Zoom>
)
```

I think I need to keep the `<Zoom>` component because it creates a wrapper div with events listeners and stuff.

Is this at all possible? How should I define `useZoom()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Zoom } from "@visx/zoom";

const initialTransform = {
  scaleX: 1.27,
  scaleY: 1.27,
  translateX: -211.62,
  translateY: 162.59,
  skewX: 0,
  skewY: 0
};

function Example({ width, height }){
   return (
  <>
     <Zoom
       width={width}
       height={height}
       scaleXMin={1 / 2}
       scaleXMax={4}
       scaleYMin={1 / 2}
       scaleYMax={4}
       transformMatrix={initialTransform}
     >
    {(zoom) => (
      <div style={{position:"relative"}} className="relative">
        <svg width={width} height={height}>
          <g transform={zoom.toString()}>
            ...
          </g>
       </svg>   
      </div>
    )}     
  </Zoom>
  </>
)
```

}

### (Please Read this api)

### API : https://medium.com/dev-genius/create-graphics-with-zoom-and-pan-with-the-visx-library-9cb6403a8ebe